# .NET gRPC on Windows 11: Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-6.0, windows-11

I can't make the following code working, it's basically [Code-first gRPC copied from MS DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in .NET 6 on Windows 11.

gRPC reflection works but invoking the specific endpoint does not.

This is the server code

```cs
using ProtoBuf.Grpc;
using ProtoBuf.Grpc.Server;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddCodeFirstGrpc();
builder.Services.AddCodeFirstGrpcReflection();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGrpcService<TestService>();
app.MapCodeFirstGrpcReflectionService();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();

[DataContract] 
public class EmptyModel { }

[ServiceContract] 
public interface ITestService 
{ 
    [OperationContract] Task<EmptyModel> Test(EmptyModel request, CallContext context);
}
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public Task<EmptyModel> Test(EmptyModel request, CallContext context)
        => Task.FromResult(new EmptyModel());
}
```

Reflection works:

```
> grpcurl localhost:64143 describe
TestService is a service:
service TestService {
  rpc Test ( .EmptyModel ) returns ( .EmptyModel );
}
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection is a service:
service ServerReflection {
  rpc ServerReflectionInfo ( stream .grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionRequest ) returns ( stream .grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionResponse );
}
```

But invoking the endpoint does not

Calling `> grpcurl -plaintext localhost:64143 ConsoleApp1.SignupService/Test` throws the following exception in the server app.

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1]
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
      System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
```

I found this exact exception only [on this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39074) but I can't connect the dots how that could be relevant. I tried restarting DEV certificates, didn't help. I use Windows 11 and I read that they have some shenanigans with TLS 1.3 so I tried to force Kestrel to TLS 1.2 but that didn't help either.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I don't know a lot about `grpcurl`, but what happens if you try with `BloomRPC` (https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc) ? You might need to re-write your model in Protocol Buffers (should be straight forward enough as it's only and `Empty` message).
Could you also share your `launchSettings.json` or whatever you are using to configure `Kestrel` ?

Comment: Actually, if you are trying to communicate using `https`, shouldn't you remove the `-plaintext` ?